# Why my Odoo 13 instance only run with debug assets?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, debugging, odoo-13

I deployed Odoo 13 on AWS. But it shows this error when connecting:

```
GET https://****-erp.sit.solpass.co/web/content/497-9d3f564/web.assets_common.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404

web?debug=0:38 GET https://****-erp.sit.solpass.co/web/content/503-4926ae1/web.assets_backend.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404

web?debug=0:39 GET https://****-erp.sit.solpass.co/web/content/504-9d3f564/web.assets_common.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

web?debug=0:40 GET https://****-erp.sit.solpass.co/web/content/505-4926ae1/web.assets_backend.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

web?debug=0:52 Uncaught TypeError: odoo.define is not a function

    at web?debug=0:52
```

I think my issue appear because my Odoo can not access these Js, Css file.

And when I access it by normal debug or debug with assets, it's run normally

Comment: Maybe `Regenerate Assets Bundles` will help

Comment: I tried this but nothing change

Comment: Now then you have to look at your server logs. Is there any file store problems?

Comment: I think it is file store problems too. After I delete all attachment and restart Odoo on my instance it's solved.

Answer (score 1):

Most critical level of issue, SnippetBucket Team is expert on ODOO to resolve all critical issues.

```
DELETE FROM ir_attachment WHERE name SIMILAR TO '%.(js|css)';
```

For ODOO 13,14 version I confirmed.

We SnippetBucket.com face critical same issues for plenty of clients. But with this SQL delete old reference, than after restart ODOO and access backend and front-end, it 1000% worked for us.

```
sudo service odoo restart
```

or

```
sudo service odoo-server restart
```

Restart based on your linux/window or mac

*Make sure when you restore your database successful restore all filestore. I better suggest on backup and restore, filestore manually copy and restore based on "data" location*

Answer (score 0):

After deleting all attachments on the database and restart Odoo on server. It was resolved

Comment: Is your issue resolved then? Or does this just help isolate the problem?

Comment: It's not be resolved. But I just want to give you more information.

Comment: then its ment that you edit your original post.

Comment: That makes sense! Could you edit your original question to include this information? That will ensure the community is taking it into account and not confusing it as an answer.